# timeout on open view in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server

When I try to use "open view" in SQL Server menagement studio to open an complex view, I met an error after about 30s execution:
SQL Execution Error.
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Actually if I execute this view in query window it only needs 36s.

I refer to this article but didn't work:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915849
Please help, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Set the timeout=0 (infinite) for both connection time-out and execution time-out.

Refer the following image.

[image: Set connection time-out=0 also Excution time-out=0]

Comment: I changed "connection time-out" to a bigger value but didn't work.

Comment: I also tried this article:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2007/12/04/sql-execution-error-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-while-opening-view-from-ssms.aspx

Comment: And It said it's related with Visual Database Tools which used by SSMS.  Anybody know details?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug, so I added it to the Connect feedback site. Vote it up, hopefully we can get it fixed.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3115872

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is solution:

Run -> regedit -> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0(or 14.0 depends on version of SSMS)\DataProject\SQLQueryTimeout

Change Value 30 to 300

Problem solved.